Will combining smooth functions by a partition of unity always give me a smooth function?
Let $\mathbb{H}^+$ be the upper half plane and $\mathbb{H}^-$ be the lower half plane. Then consider the strip $\{z: |\operatorname{Im}(z)|<1\}$. This creates an open cover of $\mathbb{R}^2$ called $\{U_1,U_2,U_3\}$ where $$U_1 =\mathbb{H}^+ \quad U_2=\mathbb{H}^- \quad  U_3 =\{z: |\operatorname{Im}(z)|<1\}.$$
Now take a partition of unity subordinate to this cover, $\{\varphi_1, \varphi_2, \varphi_3\}$. Now define smooth functions on $U_1, U_2, U_3$ denoted $f_1,f_2,f_3$. Is it the case that
$$\sum_{i=1}^3 \varphi_i(x)f_i(x)$$
is smooth on $\mathbb{R}^2$?
In other words: will combining smooth functions locally with a partition of unity always give me a smooth function? Will the partition of unity interpolate between the discontinuous parts where the charts overlap giving me a globally smooth function?

Are the $f_j$ supported in $U_j$? If no, then no.

@SeverinSchraven Suppose they are. Then does it hold?

I wanted to write it as a comment, but it got a bit long and I've turned it into an answer. I hope you don't mind.

Let me fix some notation. Let $f_j: U_j \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be smooth functions and let
$$ g_j: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, g_j(x)= \begin{cases} f_j(x),& x\in U_j,  \\ 0,& x\in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus U_j. \end{cases}$$
If we allow for general smooth functions $f_j$, then
$$ g(x) = \sum_{j=1}^3 \varphi_j(x) g_j(x) $$
will not be smooth (not even continuous).
Because $\sum_{j=1}^3 \varphi_j = 1$, we have that at least one $\varphi_j$ is nonzero on one of the other $U_k$. Wlog assume that $\varphi_1$ does not identically vanish on $\partial U_1$. Then, we can consider $f_1=1, f_2=0=f_3$. This gives
$$ g(x) = \varphi_1(x) g_1(x), $$
which is not continuous. Indeed, let $(a,0)\in \partial U_1$ such that $\varphi_1(a,0) >0$. Then
\begin{align*}
g(a,0)&=\varphi_1(a,0) g_1(a,0) = \varphi_1(a,0) \cdot 0 \\
&= 0 \neq \varphi_1(a,0) = \lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0^+} \varphi_1(a, \varepsilon) g_1(a,\varepsilon) \\
&= \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+} g(a,\varepsilon).
\end{align*}
Now in order to prevent couterexamples of this type, we would need to require that $f_j$ vanishes on $\partial U_j$. In this case it is also easy to check that $g_j$ will be smooth and therefore $g$ will be smooth.

So if the functions vanish on the boundary, then it will be smooth. thank you!

You are very welcome.
